# Does mastering a DLC song count towards the "The Complete Package" achievement on Dance Central Spotlight?

Tags: achievements, dance-central-spotlight

Dance Central Spotlight's achievement "The Complete Package" is unlocked after the player **Collect[s] every move in every routine in the game**.

The game comes with 10 songs initially, but more may be purchased as DLC. I've been able to use DLC songs to unlock achievements like "Total Pro", which requires the player to **Unlock all 10 Pro routines**. However, I'm uncertain whether or not the same applies for "The Complete Package". Does collecting every move in every routine in a DLC song count towards unlocking "The Complete Package"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLC songs do not count for the "The Complete Package" achievement.

Reading [this discussion](https://www.trueachievements.com/viewcomment.aspx?commentid=788936#vch), the user confirms that only the 10 original songs can be used to get the achievement:

> *NOTE: Some people have asked if DLC helps towards this achievement, IT DOES NOT. I have confirmed this myself. The achievement will only unlock after you have gold boomboxes for all 10 original songs in the game. Getting a gold boombox (collecting all moves for an entire song) on DLC will not work toward this achievement.

It is also confirmed by some other user:

> I can also confirm that the TA description is the Unlocked description. DLC does not count, nor will it interfere, towards this achievement, even if you've played some DLC songs.